# Regex Matches white space but not tab (php)

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

How to write a `regex` with matches whitespace but no tabs and new line?

I tried `[[:blank:]]{2,}`; however, this doesn't work for me because its whitespace or tab but not newlines.

Comment: This: `[^\S\t\n\r]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per my original comment, you can use this.

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8QvVx4/1)

**Note**: The link contains whitespace characters: *tab*, *newline*, and *space*. Only *space* is matched.

```
[^\S\t\n\r]
```

So your regex would be `[^\S\t\n\r]{2,}`

---

### Explanation

- `[^\S\t\n\r]` Match any character not present in the set.

  - `\S` Matches any non-whitespace character. Since it's a double negative it will actually match any whitespace character. Adding `\t`, `\n`, and `\r` to the negated set ensures we exclude those specific characters as well. Basically, this regex is saying:

    - Match any whitespace character except `\t\n\r`

This principle in regex is often used with word characters `\w` to negate the underscore `_` character: `[^\W_]`

Comment: Great! It is working thank you everything. I already know the very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[ ]{2,} works normally (not sure about php)
or even / {2,}/

Comment: probably also quicker than the double-negative route